# How to dock chrome developer console on the LEFT?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm aware you can click the vertical ellipsis button ( ⋮ ) and then choose to dock on the bottom, right or detach. But does anyone know how to dock on the left?

Currently I have to detach and then manually resize and adjust, which is annoying.

**Edit:** I'll just leave this question open until someone either convinces Google to add left docking, or someone figures out a hack/finds or builds an extension to get it to work.

**Edit 2:** Issue solved. Google just added this in latest standard Chrome release (v. 58)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I realise this is an old post, but it's the first result in Google*

Docking to the left was released in Chrome 58 (which came out yesterday).

Go forth and dock to left!

Answer (score 2):

Currently - Chrome Canary will help you in this case.

[image]

Comment: Nice, if it is in Canary, then I suppose it will filter down to the standard version in the not too distant future.